# Running a .sh from a .desktop [Making an icon for Minecraft.]

Tags: command-line, bash, java, scripts, minecraft

Rather recently, I've decided to add minecraft to my dock. I play it enough to want it on my dock. I created a .desktop file, and I gave it an icon, name, and such. I figured that point the exec at the .jar would be good enough, but apparently I am incorrect. I decided to make a .sh that would do the same, then point the exec at the .sh.

Code for the .desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
Exec=/home/bbnorman/.Minecraft.sh %U 
Comment=Runs Minecraft.
Icon=/home/bbnorman/Documents/Files/icon.png
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
#X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Code for the .sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(/home/bbnorman/Documents/Files/Minecraft.jar)
```

The .sh works if I use 'bash .Minecraft' in terminal, but simply will not open it via the .desktop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting the contents of the script in the `Exec` line? e.g. `Exec=echo $(/home/bbnorman/Documents/Files/Minecraft.jar)`

Comment: I have, yes. I will retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
Exec=java -jar /home/bbnorman/Documents/Files/Minecraft.jar
Comment=Runs Minecraft.
Icon=/home/bbnorman/Documents/Files/icon.png
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

Comment: @Brendon - if so, please [select the tick](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xyGzw.png) to mark this as the answer - you can change your mind later if you wish.

Comment: I did. I hope it helps. c:

Answer (score 0):

I think your script doesn't have execute permission.

```
chmod +x << your script >>
```